# how to enble the quality option in jwplayer

Tags: typescript, jwplayer

i have to give hd quality for jwplayer but it is not showing that tool bar how to add that tool?
i have used the following code

```
enter code here var playerInstance = jwplayer("jwAerialVideo");
playerInstance.setup({
//Placeholder Image
image: "//content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/<CUSTOM IMAGE ID>.jpg",
sources: [{
    file: "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/<CUSTOM VIDEO ID>.mp4",
    label: "360p SD"
  },{
    file: "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/<CUSTOM VIDEO ID>.mp4",
    label: "720p HD",
    "default": "true"
  },{
    file: "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/<CUSTOM VIDEO ID>.mp4",
    label: "1280p HD"
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend listing the highest quality variant first in your sources block because that is the first version that the player will try to play.

Second of all, try the following code example and replace all of the assets with your customer assets

```
<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
      image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
      sources: [{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo-360.mp4"
      },{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo-720.mp4"
      }]
    });
</script>
```

Finally, why bother even listing out the qualities manually? Use their delivery API:

```
https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/media/MEDIAID
```